# I am deploying MERN Webapp on vercel and this error occurs while building on vercel

Tags: npm, deployment, mern, vercel

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/ssh2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node) npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-25T08_20_12_648Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1

I am deploying MERN Webapp on vercel and this error occurs while building on vercel.